# how to sum in foreach loop in php

Tags: php, sql

this is my code i want the sum of the fields but unable to do this any one can help in this regards

```
<?php
     $hostname="localhost";  
     $username="root";  
     $password="";  
     $db = "usman";  

     $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$db", $username, $password);  

     foreach($dbh->query("SELECT COUNT(*) as cnt
     FROM ams 
     WHERE empid= {$_SESSION['sess_user_id']} 
     GROUP BY leavetype 
     HAVING leavetype =               
     sum('Absent'), sum('Annual'),sum('Medical'), 
     sum('Casual') , sum('LWOP') ") as  $GrandTotal) 
     {  
           echo "<table ><tr ><td style='border: 0px; ' >" .        
           $GrandTotal['cnt'] . "</td></tr></table>";    
           echo "<br>"; 
     }
?>
```

Comment: Anything you want to show goes after SELECT, not HAVING

Comment: `SUM(column)` and not `SUM('string')`. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_sum and make sure you started the session.

Comment: Question should have been "How do I indent my code so its readable?"

Comment: i want to add these field ..these are come from 1 coulm against id

Comment: @RiggsFolly Alas, that's a common issue.

Comment: @RiggsFolly [So, am I wrong on this one?...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39772700/how-to-sum-in-foreach-loop-in-php#comment66839747_39772700). I guess so. The score is `4-0` I see ;-)

Comment: I recognise this code. I answer this when it was a simpler query yesterday I think

Comment: @Fred-ii- No idea, this is far to complicated for me

Comment: @RiggsFolly the score was updated ;-)

Comment: Am I right in thinking that this query should return ONLY ONE ROW as its selecting on `empid= {$_SESSION['sess_user_id']} `

Comment: Mohammad, can you show us an example of the `ams` table

Comment: @RiggsFolly I feel like I'm at a hockey game.

Answer (score 1):

HAVING is a filter on grouped results, not a way to select anything

I would guess you need something like

```
SELECT 
  leavetype, 
  count(*) as cnt
FROM ams 
 where empid= {$_SESSION['sess_user_id']} 
 and leavetype in ('Absent', 'Annual','Medical',  'Casual' , 'LWOP') -- if you want only certain leave types
GROUP BY leavetype
```

If you want only the count of all these leavetypes, just do

```
SELECT 
 count(*) as cnt
FROM ams 
where empid= {$_SESSION['sess_user_id']} 
and leavetype in ('Absent', 'Annual','Medical',  'Casual' , 'LWOP')
```

Comment: The grouping probably isn't needed. Since the php only shows a count.

Comment: @LukStorms Maybe, but the "non-working" code make me think that it's desired. Who knows, who knows...

Comment: leave type is a column and i want to count the sum of all entries against emp id from this leave type column. like('Absent', 'Annual','Medical',  'Casual' , 'LWOP') in leavetype is 6 show as grand total